# C++ Previously allocated Array not reachable outside of class

Tags: c++

So I was working on a Table class in C++ which worked fine so far , but acessing the class calling the [ ]-operator from the main function seems to return a wrong value from the array despite allocating it first.

The first call ( see line with //First Comment) returns the correct value of 1 , while the second call from the main func (see //Second Comment) returns an arbitrary value despite having the same memory adress , leading to the conclusion that the array(s) are not correctly allocated (?) .Output is listed below:

```
sumofallrows: 6 
Array:[1,2,3,4,5,6] 
First element of table:      1
First element of n=1-th row: 2 
First element of n=2-th row: 4 
Created Table with 3 rows and a size of 6 in internal representation!
here at n=1 0059F800,1 
here at n=2 0059F800,-858993460
```

---

```
 template < typename T>
    class Table{

        public:
            int i, j;                                               
            int numberOfRows_;                                          
            int sumOfAllRows = 0;                                       
            int* lengthOfRows_;                                         
            T* internalArray;           
            T** startOfEachRow;
        public:
            Table(int numberOfRows, int lengthOfRows[]) :
                numberOfRows_(numberOfRows), lengthOfRows_(lengthOfRows)
            {
                for (i = 0; i < numberOfRows_; i++){
                    sumOfAllRows += lengthOfRows_[i];
                };
                cout << "sumofallrows: " << sumOfAllRows << "\n" ;
                internalArray = new T[sumOfAllRows];
                startOfEachRow = new T*[numberOfRows_];

                int offset = 0;
        //--------------------------------------------------------------//
                int tmpArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };                  //TestData for <T> = int
                internalArray = tmpArray;                               //
                cout << "Array:[" << internalArray[0];                  //
                for (i = 1; i < sumOfAllRows; i++){                     //
                    cout << "," << internalArray[i];                    //
                };                                                      //
                cout << "]\n";                                          //
        //--------------------------------------------------------------//
                startOfEachRow[0] = &internalArray[0];
                cout << "First element of table: \t" << startOfEachRow[0][0] << "\n";
                for (i = 1; i < numberOfRows_; i++){
                    offset += lengthOfRows_[i - 1];
                    startOfEachRow[i] = &internalArray[offset];
                    cout << "First element of n="<<i<<"-th row:\t" << startOfEachRow[i][0] << "\n";
                };
                cout << "Created Table with " << numberOfRows_ << " rows and a size of " << sumOfAllRows << " in internal representation!\n";
                int* tmp = new int[];
                tmp = startOfEachRow[0];
                cout << "here at n=1 " << &tmp[0] << "," << tmp[0] << "\n";//First Comment
            }

            size_t rowNum() const {
                return numberOfRows_;
            };
            size_t colNum(size_t rowIdx) const {
                return lengthOfRows_[rowIdx];
            };

            T* operator[](size_t rowIdx){
                T* ptr = startOfEachRow[rowIdx];
                return ptr;
            };

        };

           int main(int argc, char** argv) {

                int lengthOfRows[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
                int numberOfRows = 3;
                Table<int> testTable(numberOfRows, lengthOfRows);
                int* tmp = testTable[0];
                cout << "here at n=2 " << &tmp[0] << "," << tmp[0] << "\n"; //Second Comment
                return 0;
            }
```

**NOTE:**

I'm not finished yet , hence the testData .

Comment: internalarray is pointing at a local variable, which looses scope once you step out of the contructor.

Comment: Consider copying the lengthOfRows[] array.  As-is, if int lengthOfRows[] = { 1,2,3} ever goes out of scope, the Table<int> will be left pointing to deallocated memory

Comment: Thanks @MobyDisk , I'll change that in the process !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    int tmpArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; //TestData for <T> = int
    internalArray = tmpArray;
```

you overwrite your previously allocated `internalArray` (`internalArray = new T[sumOfAllRows];`) with a pointer to a temporary array.

After your Table c'tor finishes, the temporary array's storage 'vanishes' - it is re-used for other variables. You're lucky your code didn't segfault/crash.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer !! I removed the assignment and copied the array instead for anyone wondering  , +1 :)